# Can't run the node2vec algorithm with two weighted relationships

Tags: neo4j, graph-algorithm

I'm trying to run node two vec with two weighted relationships. First of all I'm creating the graph like this:

```
CALL gds.graph.create('test23','*',
 {hasprop:{type:'HAS_PROPERTIES', orientation:'UNDIRECTED', properties:'weight2'},   
 locin:{type:'LOCATES_IN', orientation:'UNDIRECTED', properties:'weight'} })
```

Node2vec Run

```
CALL gds.beta.node2vec.write('test23', 
{embeddingDimension: 10, writeProperty: "embeddingNode2vec",
 relationshipTypes:['locin','hasprop'] 
,relationshipWeightProperty:'weight, weight2' } )
```

It returns me the following error:

> Relationship weight property `weight, weight2` not found in
> relationship types ['hasprop', 'locin']. Properties existing on all
> relationship types: []

But when I'm running the cypher query with a single relationship type e.g. 'hasprop' everything works fine. Can you please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship weight property parameter can only take a single property name as the value. You could either use cypher projections to unify your relationship property name:

```
CALL gds.graph.create.cypher('test',
'MATCH (n) RETURN id(n)',
'MATCH (s)-[r:locin|hasprop]-(t)
 RETURN id(s) as source, id(t) as target, coalesce(r.weight, r.weight2) as weight')
```

And then run the node2vec as follows:

```
CALL gds.beta.node2vec.write('test23', 
{embeddingDimension: 10, writeProperty: "embeddingNode2vec",
 relationshipTypes:['locin','hasprop'] 
,relationshipWeightProperty:'weight' } )
```

Or you could refactor your stored graph to have the weight property on both relationships:

```
MATCH ()-[r:hasprop]->()
SET r.weight = r.weight2
```

And then project the graph using the unified weight property:

```
CALL gds.graph.create('test23','*',
 {hasprop:{type:'HAS_PROPERTIES', orientation:'UNDIRECTED', properties:'weight'},   
 locin:{type:'LOCATES_IN', orientation:'UNDIRECTED', properties:'weight'} })
```

Now you can run the node2vec with the same procedure as above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But relationships are between different entities in the graph. Home - LOCATES_IN- City and Home- [HAS_PROPERTY]- Property. Weights are different, too

Comment: well, you have to unify the name of the relationship weight and it will work, like in the example I showed